# System.Collections.ArrayList

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

newbie here

I have this line of code here

```
lblDepart.Text = t.DepartureCities;
```

and it returns

```
System.Collections.ArrayList
```

I guess this is an ArrayList....how would I display it properly?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by display? Web? Console? WinForm?

Comment: I have a label `lblDepart = "We are leaving from" + t.DepartureCities; and the DepartureCities are LA, Boston, Toronto...trying to get to display in the label "We are leaving from LA, Boston, Toronto.

Comment: Also, FYI, `ArrayList` is obsolete. It shouldn't be used in new code.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `ArrayList` is a collection of elements.  In order to display this value to the user you are going to have to combine all of the elements into a single `string` value.  There are different ways to do this but the easiest is to just use a comma

```
ArrayList list = t.DepartureCities;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {

  if (builder.Length > 0) {
    builder.Append(", ");
  }
  object current = list[i];
  builder.Append(current);
}
lblDeparture.Text = builder.ToString();
```

Note that `ArrayList` is generally considered to be an obsolete type in .Net.  If you control `DepartureCities` you should be using `List<T>` instead.

The reason is strong typing.  With `ArrayList` I have no idea what type of elements you are storing in the collection: `string`, `City`, etc ...  With `List<T>` it's trivially apparent because it will directly state the elements that it contains: `List<string>`, `List<City>`, etc ...

Comment: Bonus points for telling the user that List<T> is preferred for framework's >= 2.0

Comment: I got this error `The type or namespace name 'StringBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) `

Comment: @user979331 make sure to add `using System.Text` to the top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
lblDepart.Text = String.Join(",", t.DepartureCities.OfType<YourType>());
```

Change `YourType` accordingly. Maybe `City` ?

Comment: I get an error with this `The type or namespace name 'YourType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) `

Comment: @user979331 You should replace `YourType` with  the correct type. What is in `t.DepartureCities` ?

Comment: That I am not sure of...I tried City and ListItem and I got this error `System.Collections.ArrayList' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' `

Comment: @user979331 don't forget `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

If you call

```
lblDepart.Text = t.DepartureCities;
```

then this implicitly calls

```
lblDepart.Text = t.DepartureCities.ToString();
```

and the `ToString()`-method of these built-in types usually returns the name of the object.
The object is a `Collection`-object containing several individual objects.
If you want to access individual items, use

```
foreach(var item in t.DepartureCities){
//use item in here
}
```